# Integrate Semantic UI CSS into Laravel 5.5

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, semantic-ui

I am building an app with Laravel and I want to switch to Semantic UI over Bootstrap. I followed the [docs](https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html#install-semantic-ui%22%20target=%22_blank) but I am baffled.

Is there any straight way to ineteregrate semantic-ui with Laravel 5.5?

Answer (score 0):

Just include these in your 'index.html' and remove the bootstrap ones and you're gtg.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But, is there any local method?

Comment: Yes, open those links in browser and save all three files in your local project directory named jquery.min.js , semantic.min.css and semantic.min.js respectively & replace path in the tags with the local one where those files are located.